# Extract numbers in after the string foo: with regex

Tags: .net, regex

i have data like this:

```
xxx 4145 xx foo: 85 - 123 , [8545:2] yy rr 99
foo: 41 74 foo: 858 10 32 foo: 554 04 y
```

i want extract numbers after `foo:`, if multiple `foo:` only second `foo:` must be matched

the output desired:

```
85
123
8545 
2
858
10 
32
```

I tested:

```
(?x)
(?:
    (?:foo:)? .*? foo:[ ]
  |
    \G(?!^)[-: \[\],]
)
(\d+)
```

but it return in match(1)

```
85
885
554
04
```

[DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3A(%3F%3Afoo%3A)%3F.*%3Ffoo%3A%20%7C%5CG(%3F!%5E)%5B-%3A%20%5C%5B%5C%5D%20%5D)(%5Cd%2B)&i=xxx%204145%20xx%20foo%3A%2085%20-%20123%20%2C%20%5B8545%3A2%5D%20yy%20rr%2099%0D%0Afoo%3A%2041%2074%20foo%3A%20858%2010%2032%20foo%3A%20554%2004%20y)

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can play with your regex at http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: +1 also, Why all those downvotes?

Comment: @chepsi why 99 isn't extracted?

Comment: You say that only the second `foo:` must be matched, but in the desired output the first and the third is matched. Do you mean every other `foo:`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: nmber must be contiguous

Comment: @AvinashRaj: it return also '41 74'

Comment: @AvinashRaj: i tryed in regewstorm (.NET engine) and it return '41 71'

Comment: @chepsi see the magic after enabling the multiline modifier.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: genuis..could you explain your pattern

Comment: yes and +1 for your genuiosity :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj: yes it work for me. i use .NET engine for this work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one-regex solution (the numbers are in the first capturing group, see [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/cQ2cF4/13)):

```
(?m:^.*?(?:foo:.*?)?foo:\s*|(?!^)\G)[^A-Za-z0-9]*(\d+)
```

**Explanation**

```
(?m:                   # multiline
  ^.*?(?:foo:.*?)?foo: # either match everythg until the second 'foo:' if there
                       # are two, the first otherwise
|                      # or
  (?!^)\G              # check we have already matched something
)
[^A-Za-z0-9]*          # eat every non alphanum character...
(\d+)                  # until the number we want to match
```

We make sure we are in the relevant digit part with `(?:^.*?(?:foo:.*?)?foo:\s*|(?!^)\G)`: either we match everything until the correct `foo:`, or we check we have already matched something with the anchor `(?!^)\G`.

We then consume everything that's not an alphanumeric character (since we don't want to match digits after other letters) and capture the numbers.

Comment: but it fail if the content: 'xxx 4145 xx foo: 85 - 123 , [8545:2] yy rr 99 foo: 001' why ?

Comment: @walidtoumi From OP: "if multiple `foo:` only second `foo:` must be matched". The regex extracts `001` from `xxx 4145 xx foo: 85 - 123 , [8545:2] yy rr 99 foo: 001`, ie the digits after the second `foo:`. Why is that a failure?

Comment: ah my mistake..could you please explain why if i put (\d+) outside of non-capturing group it not work: '(?m:^.*?(?:foo:.*?)?foo:|(?!^)\G[^A-Za-z0-9]*)(\d+)'

Comment: @walidtoumi: there is no space after `foo:` in the regex, so `foo:(\d+)` doesn't match anything and the `\G` anchor always fails. Adding  `\s*` makes it [work again](http://regex101.com/r/cQ2cF4/10) ! Also, be aware you can use [inline code markup in comments](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) using backticks `\`` :)

Comment: @walidtoumi: actually, this is better solved by putting `[^A-Za-z0-9]*(\d+)` outside the non capturing group, avoiding a useless match. That's an improvement, thanks !

Comment: You can also avoid using shortcut `\d\s` to match only ascii chars.. `(?m:^.*?(?:foo:.*?)?foo:[ ]*|(?!^)\G)[^A-Za-z0-9]*([0-9]+)` thanks Robin